# Docker Containers created with Docker Compose can't communicate with each other

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, vaadin, docker-container

I tried to set up two Docker containers with docker compose (Vaadin app and MariaDB database).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
 vaadin-app:
  build:
   context: .
  container_name: vaadin-app
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  depends_on:
   - mariadb
   
 mariadb:
  image: "mariadb:10.5.8"
  container_name: mariadb
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
   MYSQL_DATABASE: Test
   MYSQL_USER: test2
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: test2
  volumes:
   - data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
   - 3306:3306

volumes:
 data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
COPY target/contacts-md-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
logging.level.org.atmosphere = warn
spring.mustache.check-template-location = false

# Launch the default browser when starting the application in development mode
vaadin.launch-browser=true
# To improve the performance during development.
# For more information https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-configuration.html#special-configuration-parameters
vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com.vaadin,org.vaadin,dev.hilla,com.example.contacts
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

# Database stuff
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mariadb:3306/Test
spring.datasource.username=test2
spring.datasource.password=test2
spring.sql.init.mode=always

# Hibernate stuff
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

When I try to set it up with docker-compose, the vaadin-app container exits after a few seconds and I get the following error log:

```
vaadin-app  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
vaadin-app  |
vaadin-app  |
vaadin-app  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:119) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   ... 62 common frames omitted
vaadin-app  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
vaadin-app  |   ... 65 common frames omitted
```

I have already tried to declare a custom network for both containers, which hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a network should be the correct step, without, none of them knows of each other. We have yet one compose file per every Image. Here how it looks at us:

Below mariadb ports you may add

```
networks:
  - my-sql-network
```

And at the end should be

```
networks:
  my-sql-network:
    name: my-sql-network
    driver: bridge
```

Nearly the same in the Apps yaml:

```
networks:
  - my-sql-network
```

and at the end

```
networks:
  my-sql-network:
    external: true
```

I hope it's of any help for you!

Comment: you dont necessarily need to define networks for apps in same docker-compose file, as docker-compose automatically creates a network and binds the apps in the same network, if it is not defined explicitly... If it is defined, then it uses that network only

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not network related, as a default network is created automatically by docker-compose, if the apps are in same docker-compose file and don't have any other network specified explicitly.

The issue is your app tries to communicate to mariadb, as soon as its up but mariadb isn't currently fully up to accept connections. The `depends_on` only checks if the container has started, it doesn't wait for inside app to be up as it doesn't know which app will take how much time. You can even test it by running `docker-compose up -d`

and see your app will fail and then again run `docker compose up -d`, now only your app will re-run but mariadb will already be up.

So you can Add Healtcheck on mariadb container to wait until it becomes fully healthy and then mark it as UP

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. The mariadb container keeps running, but everytime I run docker compose up -d the vaadin-app container starts only to exit after a few seconds with the same error log.

Comment: Then there might be an issue in your app configuration, I have tried it with a simple ubuntu image, with curl installed and it works fine... am able to curl mariadb:3306 the 2nd time